# Unable to Create the Web site 'http://localhost/WindowsService'. The Web server 'http://localhost' could not be found

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, localhost

I am working on a Windows Service and whenever I try to publish it, the error is thrown. I have already installed the service through installutil. I would like to test the module I've added before I commit.

Comment: Is this a self-service web service using WCF?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's a service which needs installutil.exe. My co-worker and I work on the same project (but on different modules) and his worked fine and was published. My wild guess is because I did not use the install.bat to execute installutil.exe, instead, I did it manually through the command prompt. What I'm gonna do is uninstall the WindowsService and install it again using the .bat file.

Comment: I would highly recommend using topshelf http://topshelf-project.com/ to build window service. Installing services are as simple as /path/service.exe install.

Answer (score 0):

It appears IIS was turned off in Windows features so I just turned it on (opted in IIS).